# Boto3 does not list my Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elb

I am new to boto3 and am using it for automating the process of register and deregister EC2 instances from load balancers.

This is my sample Python code:

```
import boto3
elbList = boto3.client('elb')
bals = elbList.describe_load_balancers()
for elb in bals['LoadBalancerDescriptions']:
    print 'ELB Name:' + elb['LoadBalancerName'] +  'ELB scheme type: ' + elb['Scheme']
```

This script only lists all my **classic load balancers** but my **application load balancers are not listed**.

How do I list my application load balancer and list all the instances attached to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strangely enough, Application Load Balancers are only visible via the `v2` interface:

```
client = boto3.client('elbv2')
response = client.describe_load_balancers()
```

See: [boto3 ElasticLoadBalancingv2 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#elasticloadbalancingv2)

Comment: Maybe thats why they made an 'elbv2'?